# Best/standard method of generating a users unique id?

Tags: php, encryption, authentication, token, access-token

I'm working on a login script and am trying to make it a lot more secure than I've done in the past. Before I used to just store the hash of a `uniqid()` and would store that as a session on user login. Now I'm using the following function to create a UID but think it might be a bit overkill. It returns a 64 character string.

```
private function _createUid() {
    $bytes = random_bytes(32);
    $uid = bin2hex($bytes);

    return $uid;
}
```

Now my question is, what is the standard method of storing a login unique id / token? I'm not referring to a remember me because that's a whole different story but just a typical login and what I should store as the UID.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I think JWT tokens are an excellent way to store sessions since it requires no database access to verify and can expire whenever you like.  You haven't really stated what you are trying to achieve exactly.  Are these IDs sent to the server to verify the client or?

Comment: Its not the string length necessarily that should cause worries. Combining uniqueness with validation is a good way to go. You should check the session value against something stored server side. E.g. a database entry on each request. JWT as Luke pointed out is excellent method to authenticate. Even with JWT you can verify the values you attach to the json token on each request.

Comment: You don't need this, because you already have it - the session ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply used what I was using. It seems that a userid can be generated in many different ways and no one way is correct.